Converting theorem environment using pandoc without style
When trying to convert LaTeX into markdown using Pandoc, I noticed that it automatically saves the style of theorem environments into the AST files in the middle. For example, for this latex file
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{Plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[title of theorem]
content of theorem
\end{thm}

\end{document}

when I convert it using Pandoc, I get
Div ("",["thm"],[]) [
    Para [
        Strong [Str "Theorem",Space,Str "1"],Space,
        Str "(title",Space,Str "of",Space,Str "theorem).",Space,Space,
        Emph [Str "content",Space,Str "of",Space,Str "theorem"]
    ]
]

So the numbering and the word "Theorem" appears in Strong, the title in plain, but with brackets, and the rest of the content in Emph.
I tried removing the \theoremstyle{Plain} from the LaTex file, which gave the same result. I tried to add a custom style with \newtheoremstyle but Pandoc just said that it doesn't recognize that command and skipped it. If I remove the \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} from the LaTeX file, then the style is gone, by so is the title of the Theorem:
Div ("",["thm"],[]) [
    Para [Str "content",Space,Str "of",Space,Str "theorem"]
]

Is there a simple way to get the numbering + title + content, but without the automatic style?
More generally, is there an easy way (which doesn't involve learning haskell) to customize this conversion? In the output I would like to treat the numbering and title in a certain way, and the fact that pandoc puts them as text + emph\strong\brackets just means that I need to somehow extract them back by using either a filter, or process the output file. For example, I would like the conversion to be something like:
Div ("",["thm"],[("number", "1")]) [
    Div ("",["title"],[]) [
        Para [Str "title",Space,Str "of",Space,Str "theorem"]
    ]
    Div ("",["content"],[]) [
        Para [                 
            Str "content",Space,Str "of",Space,Str "theorem"
        ]
    ]
]


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Maybe a filter could do the job. I mean, a lua filter would most definitely do the job but it could be considered to be a topic that is off topic here...

@DG' Initially I tried to solve it with a filter, by removing the "Strong" and extracting the numbering \ title, but then noticed that in other environment it is sometimes "Emph" instead, and sometimes plain, and I am not even sure if and what are the other possibilities. This is without mentioning that the same style appears inside the content which then I need to remove paragraph by paragraph. This means that I work hard to remove the styling that pandoc worked hard to add, instead of telling it not to add it to begin with.
